# How do I communicate to a serial com port through a Python command in Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to communicate with a serial com port through Jupyter Notebooks. I need to be able to send commands for the serial device to run. This can be done through Hyperterminal commands but I need to be able to do this through a Python command in Jupyter.

I've tried using the write function of Pyserial but the strings that I send through Pyserial won't execute in the serial com port. I've implemented it like below:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()  
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.port = 'COM25'
ser.write(b'!!!!!')     
ser.close()
```

Since "!!!!!" is the command needing to be executed by the serial device, is there a way to send this to the device through Python?

Comment: Hello Griffin, a couple of questions: have you tried first opening the port and setting it up and then in a different Jupyter cell sending the `ser.write()` command? sometimes you have to wait a bit for the port to be ready after you open it. There might be other issues like permissions, what OS are you on? Are you using Anaconda? Have you installed the serial package yourself? You might also want to try from a Python terminal instead of from Jupyter and do a loopback test (wire TX to RX on your port to see if you get an echo back).

Comment: @MarcosG. Thank you for your insight. ser.write() was used in a different cell unsuccessfully. I'm using Windows and have not gave any permissions but I don't know if I should? I am using Anaconda and I have installed the pyserial package myself. I'll look into using a Python terminal but the final product has to be in Jupyter. How would I go about doing a loopback test? This is my first time working with serial ports

Comment: if you are running Hyperterminal as a normal user and it works I suppose you should not need to give any special permission. To be honest I don't remember ever trying to use pyserial from Jupyter, at least not recently. I'm on Linux but I can give it a try right now and let you know if I can make it work. You can take a look at the loopback test on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu7Z2FryD_A), if your port is the old-shool RS232 connector there are other videos

Comment: I just checked and my ports work fine from jupyter. I had to add `ser.open()` before writing but I guess that's different on Windows. If you are not getting any errors maybe you should check if your setup is the same you are successfully using with Hyperterminal. Right now you are doing 8N1: 8 bits data, 1 stop bit and no parity, is that correct?